# Downloading data in chunks in J2ME

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me, inputstream

I have to fetch larger amount of data from text file, which is stored in device memory. And need to send the data chunks read from the file to server. As the file has huge data, I want to break the data into chunks while fetching from filesystem. Currently my logic is fetching data in one shot.

```
try {
            fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path, Connector.READ);

            if (fc.exists()) {
                int size = (int) fc.fileSize();
                is = fc.openInputStream();
                byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
                is.read(bytes, 0, size);
                //System.out.println("Text: " + str);

            }
        } catch (Exception ioe) {}
```

This works, but i want to set the data chunk size to a fixed value. and then iteratively it should fetch the whole file data and send to server. Can you please suggest me a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following utility method:

```
public static int copy (InputStream is, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte [] buff = new byte[1024];
    int len = is.read(buff);
    int total = 0;

    while (len > 0) {
        total += len;
        out.write(buff, 0, len);
        len = is.read(buff);
    }

    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use InputStream.skip to jump to a particular part of your file.

Keep an index somewhere to know how much you read already.

Use a fixed-size chunk (a few Kos), and jump to chunk-size*index when you read.

Comment: Do I have to put the entire logic of fetching file from memory card and opening Stream connection inside a loop?

Comment: i don't think so, but you can.